# Why doesn't git rebase lead to a linear project history

Tags: git

My steps are as follows:

A.`git checkout -b feature-a`

B.Edit some files

C.`git commit`

D.`git push origin feature-a`

E.Create a merge request on gitlab

F.Accept by my teammates，merge into develop branch

G.`git rebase origin/develop`

My expectation would be, that the commit history is now linear, but it isn't. What is the reason?

Comment: Did you use  `git add <files>` before commiting ??

Comment: of couse I used `git add <files>`

Comment: which branch are you in when you invoke the last command? could you specifiy "just a mess" a little bit more?

Comment: My local develop branch，"just a mess" means I expect it to be linear,but it not linear, shoud I do `git rebase origin/develop` before push? @Gernot

Comment: If your pull request has been merged into the development branch, there is a merge commit. So the history of the development branch is not linear. (as your feature branch starts somewhere from your development branch and is merged in again). To obtain a linear history, you teammate would have to rebase the development branch on the feature branch. Does this answer your question @phieo?

Comment: Thanks,The merge operation(accept merge request) is done my gitlab, so it is a `merge` not a `rebase`,maybe it is the point. @Gernot

Comment: @phieo ok then I'll state this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, git will record your commit history in DAGs (Directed Acyclic Graphs), but you can use `git log --first-parent` to retrieve a  linear project history.

Answer (score 0):

If your pull request has been merged into the development branch, there is a merge commit. So the history of the development branch is not linear. (as your feature branch starts somewhere from your development branch and is merged in again).

To obtain a linear history, you teammate would have to rebase the development branch on the feature branch.

Comment: As a side note, generally speaking, if you work with other people and use feature branches (proper gitflow workflow) you would not want a simple linear history (I personally insist on --no-ff on merges) because you WANT to see the feature branches as branches in your history. So you'd want your history as linear as possible but no more than that.